How to convert a Series of Strings into an Array or Vec of Strings
I'm having a hard time converting a Series of strings into an array to iterate in a for loop.
Each item in the Series should be passed to the lit() expression, to limit the DataFrame on the specific date.
Then, the DataFrames are converted into an ndarray for matrix alg, then passed into a new DataFrame that is pushed & collected into a Vec.
#[pyfunction]
fn factor_returns(pydf: PyDataFrame, endog: Vec<String>) -> PyResult<PyDataFrame> {
    let endog_str: Vec<&str> = endog.iter().map(|s| s.as_str()).collect();
    let df: DataFrame = pydf.into();
    
     let unique_dates = df.clone()
     .lazy()
     .select([col("date").unique()])
     .collect() 
     .expect("could not collect");
    
   
    // let dates = ["2022-12-01","2022-11-11"];

    let dates = &unique_dates["date"];

   let mut factor_data_dfs: Vec<DataFrame> = vec![]; 
     
   for date in dates.iter(){
        println!("{:?}", date);
     
        let df_date = df.clone()
            .lazy()
            .filter(col("date").eq(lit(date)))
            .select([
                cols(&endog_str),
                col("log_returns"),
            ])
            .collect()
            .expect("could not collect");

        let exposures = df_date.clone()
            .lazy()
            .select([
                cols(&endog_str),
            ])
            .collect()
            .expect("could not collect");
    
        let returns_vector = df_date.clone()
            .lazy()
            .select([col("log_returns")])
            .collect()
            .expect("could not collect");
    
        let ndarray_exposures = exposures.to_ndarray::<Float64Type>(IndexOrder::Fortran).unwrap();
        let ndarray_returns = returns_vector.to_ndarray::<Float64Type>(IndexOrder::Fortran).unwrap();
        let ma_mb = ndarray_exposures.t().dot(&ndarray_returns);
        let ma_ma = ndarray_exposures.t().dot(&ndarray_exposures);
        let ma_ma_inv = ma_ma.inv().unwrap();
        let ma = ma_ma_inv.dot(&ma_mb);

        let ma_vec: Vec<f64> = ma.iter().cloned().collect();
        let ma = Series::new("factor_returns", &ma_vec);
        let endog_factor_names = Series::new("factor_names", &endog_str);

        
        let data_ma_df = df!(
            "date" => [date],
            "factor_names" => [endog_factor_names],
            "factor_returns" => [ma],
        ).unwrap();
       
       factor_data_dfs.push(data_ma_df);


    }
    Ok(PyDataFrame())
}

When iterating let dates = &unique_dates["date"]; This will return an error on lit(date) which requires a bound (not being passed as a string).
Here is the error when iterating on let dates = &unique_dates["date"];
error[E0277]: the trait bound `AnyValue<'_>: polars::prelude::Literal` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:144:40
    |
144 |             .filter(col("date").eq(lit(date)))
    |                                    --- ^^^^ the trait `polars::prelude::Literal` is not implemented for `AnyValue<'_>`
    |                                    |
    |                                    required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `polars::prelude::Literal`:
              bool
              i8
              i16
              i32
              i64
              u32
              u64
              f32
            and 11 others
note: required by a bound in `polars::prelude::lit`

I've also tried using.filter(col("date").eq(lit(date.to_string())))  which results in LAPACK error since it is passing String("2023-09-07") instead of "2023-09-07". (Cargo compiles successfully")
String("2023-09-07") 
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at src/lib.rs:170:37:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Lapack(LapackComputationalFailure { return_code: 1 })
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 59, in <module>
    df3 = factor_analysis.factor_returns(df2,endog)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Lapack(LapackComputationalFailure { return_code: 1 })
python example.py  112.76s user 12.06s system 1031% cpu 12.104 total

When passing an array of dates using let dates = ["2022-12-01","2022-11-11"]; will work and return the proper result. The date iteration is also printing the correct string format and not wrapped with String("")
"2022-12-01"
shape: (1, 3)
┌────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ date       ┆ factor_names                      ┆ factor_returns                  │
│ ---        ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                             │
│ str        ┆ list[str]                         ┆ list[f64]                       │
╞════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2022-12-01 ┆ ["factor1_xxis_intercept", "mome… ┆ [0.048018, 0.08863, … 0.008414] │
└────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘

Here is a similar post to convert PolarsNumericType into a vector
How to get a Vec from polars Series or ChunkedArray?
Here is what the Polars Series returns.
shape: (781,)
Series: 'date' [str]
[
        "2023-02-02"
        "2022-11-17"
        "2022-03-08"
        "2021-06-24"
        "2022-04-13"
        …
        "2021-01-15"
        "2023-08-24"
        "2022-10-07"
        "2021-08-16"
        "2023-01-10"
]


Can you explain why this comment doesn't work for you? Also please add the complete error message from your compiler (cargo build) with erroneous code.

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Can't you just use groupby?

Hi @cafce25, the reason why is that I believe utf8 is not a part of PolarsNumericType which can use the to_vec(). Also, the error code is due to lit() not being passed as a string.
When doing cargo build, this will return the LAPACK error for the matrix calculation. I can provide the different errors in the body. But, the code will work if passing the list of dates directly let dates = ["2022-12-01","2022-11-11"];.

Please post all the errors from cargo check/cargo build.

Hi @ChayimFriedman,
I provided the full example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Essentially, iterating by each date to perform the matrix calc, then passing it into a new data frame with the df! macro. I think groupby would also accomplish the same thing.

Hi @ChayimFriedman
I provided the errors above.

I'll repeat: your life will probably be easier (and more efficient) if you will use group_by().

Hi @ChayimFriedman I will go ahead and rewrite it using group_by() and try implementing a custom expression for the mmult portion.
